# Select JSON keys that exists in all rows of a JSON column in a database table

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I don't know if it is possible, but i am trying to create a query that returns as a result the keys that are present in all rows. I tried with:

```
SELECT JSON_KEYS(content) AS json_keys FROM cars GROUP BY json_keys
```

But this returns all keys for each table row.

Ideally i would get a single result containing the keys that exist in all rows. Is it possible using mysql/mariadb built-in features?

Comment: JSON_KEYS then JSON_TABLE then SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: When you start needing to look inside all rows in a table for certain json elements like this, it's time to start thinking about extracting those elements to their own columns in the table to up set at INSERT/UPDATE time. This can, without any exaggeration, improve performance by multiple orders of magnitude.

Comment: could you provide how the query would be? @Akina

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this is not a production database. in fact we want to extract all possible keys exatly to start planning how to extract them to their own collumns

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. They pointed you in the right direction so you can do it yourself. If you can't get it working, post your attempted code and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Please be specific about which brand and version of database you use. MySQL and MariaDB have different implementation for JSON functions, so any solution for one won't necessarily be usable for the other. Run `SELECT VERSION();` and tell us exactly what it returns.

Comment: @Barmar that said, it is very hard to go from the docs for json table to understanding how to use it for a particular case

Comment: @ysth I realize that learning new things can be hard. But if you can't figure out things from the documentation, you won't make it as a professional programmer. They can't expect everything to be spoon-fed to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Akina's comment:

json_table is the tool to use for this; it can produce multiple rows (so syntactically appears where you'd expect a joined table, not a regular function or column) from each row it is joined to.  It requires mysql 8+ or mariadb 10.6+.

```
select distinct `key`
from cars
cross join json_table(
  json_keys(cars.content),
  '$[*]' columns(`key` text path '$')
) `keys`
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/VL9uLPcl

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for helping without trying to give life lessons.

Comment: variations on this question come up a lot, but I don't see any that present a clear, accepted answer; ideally there would have been such an answer and this question be closed as a duplicate